# Android: Customize android default navigation back button at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, navigationbar

How to customize android device default back button displayed at the bottom of the screen or to make this navigation default back button invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

Try this code to hide System's default bottom navigation bar:

```
findViewById(R.id.main_layout).setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 1):

Which device are you using? Nexus?

One solution can be.. overriding the onBackPressed() method, and making it empty..so that nothing happens on its pressing..

Like this:

public void onBackPressed() {//No implementation};

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i want to change the icon of default back button visible at the bottom of the android screen or make it invisible throughout my app. Sir i want to customize android device default back button which you see at bottom of screen with home & recent apps button. If you have suggestion please answer...

Comment: It is part of the core OS design, you will not be able to change it as of my knowledge..

Comment: Implemented the solution to the question, which i have answered below. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, to my knowledge, make it go away. Keep in mind that on older devices, these are sometimes hardware buttons.

You can make it nonfunctional though, as Stealz suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```